# Bibliography compilation problem

Tags: bibliographies

I've my latex file as,

```
 % !TeX spellcheck = <none>
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=3cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{natbib}
%%\usepackage{biblatex}
%%\usepackage{bibtex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    %titlepage
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{center}
        
            %University logo
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{qau3.jpg}
            \par
            \vspace{1cm}
            %Thesis title
            {\LARGE{\textbf{Study of the Production of the Drell-Yan Cross-Section in $\mu^{-}\mu^{+}$ channel with $\sqrt{s} = 13 \;\; TeV$ using $2016$ CMS Data}\par}}
            \vspace{1cm}
            {\LARGE $\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot-\odot$}
            \newline\newline\newline
            %Author's name
        \textbf{{{ \underline{{\large Author:} Muhammad Jamshid}}}}
        \hfill
        \textbf{{{ \underline{{\large Supervisor:} Shamona Fawad Qazi}}}} \\
        {\normalsize { mjamshid@phys.qau.edu.pk}}
        \hfill
        {\normalsize { shamona@phys.qau.edu.pk}}
        \newline \newline
            %Degree
            {\large A thesis submitted for the partial fulfillment of degree of master of philosophy (M.Phil) in the department of physics, Quaid-I-Azam university, Islamabad\par}
        
            %Date
            {\Large September 2020}
        
    \end{center}
    \clearpage
\newpage
\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{Abstract}
\chapter*{Aknowledgement}
\input{Aknowledgement}
\chapter*{Declaration}
\input{Declaration}
\chapter*{Dedication to}
\input{Dedication}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction to the Standard Model}
\input{chapter 11}
\chapter{Relativistic Particle Kinematics}
\input{chapter 12}
\chapter{Accelerators and Colliders Experiments}
\input{chapter 13}
\chapter{Structure of Hadrons in QCD}
\input{chapter 14}
\chapter{Anaylsis and Results}
\input{chapter 15}
\chapter*{Conclusions}

\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{thesisstyle}
\end{document}
```

But when I try to run it, I get "?" instead of citation number the bibliography does not compile and I get the following error......

```
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file My Thesis.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file My Thesis.aux
(There were 2 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Can anyone help how can I fix this problem.....???

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Did you verify that `References.bib` and `thesisstye.bst` are in the search path of BibTeX?

Comment: I've a seperate References.bib file that contain citations....Can anyone help me..??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BibTeX](https://ctan.org/pkg/bibtex) and [Biber](https://ctan.org/pkg/biber) are no packages in the LaTeX sense, but backends (programs) to generate the bibliography that can be called from [Natbib](https://ctan.org/pkg/natbib) or [BibLaTex](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). In order of flexibility, use [BibLaTex(Biber)](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX), [BibLaTex(BibTex)](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX) or [NatBib(BibTex)](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_natbib). The second, BibLaTex(BibTex), is currently the *de facto* standard.

1. The .bib file should be in your working directory, in this case `References.bib`, and have the proper format ([sample1](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_with_natbib#The_bibliography_file) [sample2](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibliography_management_in_LaTeX#The_bibliography_file)).
2. The .bst file should be in your working directory, in this case `thesisstyle.bst`.
3. The style should be set before the bibliography is generated, in this case:

```
\bibliography{References}
\bibliographystyle{thesisstyle}
```

4. Most importantly, the document body should include citations via [the `\cite` command](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management).
5. Before using BibTex/Biber, first compile the .tex file which will mark in the .aux file the required calls.

For detailed information, refer to [this entry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25701/bibtex-vs-biber-and-biblatex-vs-natbib).

Comment: Yes, dear vitaminace33.............I've my References.bib file in the Latex working directory and I've included citations with  the \cite command.

Comment: Try to comment all the input lines and compile. Then add a single citation on the main file and compile. Then comment out the input lines one by one (or in halves). You might have a different problem than you think. Also read the links I provided (they are quite educational) and avoid using file names with white spaces.